# Meaning of the coefficient of $x^r$ in this continued product

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

[image]

Can someone please explain the 6th line of the explanation: "Also the coefficient of $x^r$ in the product is the number of ways of taking $r$ of the letters $a, b, c,\dots$"?

I cannot understand how the coefficient  of $x^r$ in the continued product $(1+ax+a^2 x^2+\dots+a^p x^p)(1+bx+b^2 x^2+\dots+b^p x^p)(1+cx+c^2 x^2+\dots+c^p x^p)$ is the **number of ways** of taking $r$ of the letters $a, b, c,\dots$. How is it the number of ways? Also is there any relation between this concept and the distribution of balls into bins?

Comment: FYI, this seems to be an example of using a generating function. Since they can sometimes be quite useful in various fields, in particular such as combinatorics, you may be interested in reading the MSE post [How can I learn about generating functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3142386/how-can-i-learn-about-generating-functions/3142387).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to calculate the $x^r$ coefficient we must select $r$ of the letters in a number of ways. This number of ways is given by the **number of terms** in the coefficient of $x^r$. For example,
$$(1+ax+a^2 x^2+\dots+a^p x^p)(1+bx+b^2 x^2+\dots+b^p x^p)(1+cx+c^2 c^2+\dots+c^p x^p)$$
$$=1+(a+b+c)x+(a^2+ab+ac+b^2+bc+c^2)x^2+\dots$$
The **number of terms** in the $x^r$ coefficients are $1,3,6,\dots$ for $r=1,2,3,\dots$ and these values correspond to the number of ways to select $r$ of the letters $a,b,c$ with the restriction that the maximum number of $a$'s, $b$'s and $c$'s is $p$.

Comment: So the author meant **number of terms** in the coefficient of $x^r$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, because $(a+b+c)$ is not equal to the number of ways to select $1$ of the letters $a,b,c$ - 3.