# n students standing in line are to be divided into teams and in each team appointed a captain. How many ways to do that? (I need last transformation)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

There are $n$ students in the class. They stand in a line in front of the teacher, who is to divide them into any number of non-empty teams (in particular, the sets can be of size $1$ or $n$) and in each set appoint a captain. A team can only consist of students standing consecutively in the line. In how many different ways can the teacher do this?

Arrange a suitable equation or system of recursive equations and determine the general formula.

---

I belive that the same question was asked right here: [Counting the number of ways to divide into teams - complicated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330210/counting-the-number-of-ways-to-divide-into-teams-complicated)

There's no concrete solution provided so I tried to get my own.

I calculated manually the numbers of sequences for some of the initial values of $n$:

- $a_1 = 1$ (because we can have just $1$ team and $1$ captain of that team)
- $a_2 = 1 + 2 = 3$ (because we can have $2$ teams in which case the captains are obvious or $1$ team in which case we need to choose the captain in one of $2$ ways)
- $a_3 = 1 + 2 \cdot 2 + 3 = 8$ (because we can have $3$ teams in which case the captains are obvious or we can have in $2$ ways $2$ teams of $1 + 2$ students in which case we need to choose the captain in one of $2$ ways or we can have one big team of $3$ students for which we need to choose the captain in one of $3$ ways)
- $a_4 = 1 + 2 \cdot 3 + 2 \cdot 2 + 3 \cdot 2 + 4 = 21$ (because we can have $4$ teams in which case the captain are obvious or we can have in $2$ ways $2$ teams of $1 + 3$ students in which case we need to choose the captain in one of $3$ ways or we can have in one way $2$ teams of $2+2$ students in which case we can choose $2$ captains in $2$ ways each or we can have in $3$ ways $3$ teams of $1 + 1 + 2$ students in which case we can choose captain in $2$ ways or we can have one big team of $4$ students for which we need to choose the captain in one of $4$ ways)

When we add one student in the line at the plece n, we have:

- one big team with n students (so we can choose the captain of that team in one of n ways) and...
- as many teams with captains as in the line of lenght n-1, but we have that one 'new student' alone in his own team and...
- as many teams with captains as in the line of lenght n-2, but we have that one 'new student' in a team of 2 (so we can choose the captain of that team in one of 2 ways) and...
- as many teams with captains as in the line of lenght n-3, but we have that one 'new student' in a team of 3 (so we can choose the captain of that team in one of 3 ways) and so on

Therefore, I thought that the recurrence equation would look like this:

$a_n = n + a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2} + 3a_{n-3} +...$

As you can see while comparing with the numbers of sequences for some of the initial values of $n$ (those that I calculated manually above), the formula does work.

Now, from the comments below I know that the general formula needs to be of form: $a_n = 3a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}$

---

Could somebody explain to me how to get from:
$$a_n = n + a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2} + 3a_{n-3} +...$$
to:
$$a_n = 3a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}$$
?

I would like to see an algebraic way of transformation, not a proof by induction.

Comment: That regression works...but you need to add $n$ (or just define $a_0=1$ to make the form hold).

Comment: The sequence in question is [A001906](https://oeis.org/A001906).

Comment: @lulu where that $n$ comes from? In my interpretation - what are those $n$?

Comment: I am using your notation.  $n$ is the number of students.  But, really, just set $a_0=1$.  Makes everything simpler.

Comment: Ok, but in the context of "story" that I provided (that starts with: "When we add one student in the line at the plece n, we have:") - why I should add that $n$? What is that $n$ in that context? @lulu

Comment: Because, in your recursion, you left off the case where there is just one team with $n$ students.  In that case there are $n$ choices for captain, so you need to add those $n$.  To keep the form of the recursion, you are adding the term $n\times a_0$.

Comment: @lulu Ok, great! Now I get it. But, last thing - how to get $a_n = 3a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}$ form $a_n = n + a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + a_{n-3} + ...$ ?

Comment: I'm sure there's a good combinatorial argument (which I don't see at the moment), but you should easily be able to prove it inductively.

Comment: @lulu ok. I don't see that either. Thank you for your help. I updated the question, Maybe someone else will be able to help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could somebody explain to me how to get from:
> $$a_n = n + a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2} + 3a_{n-3} +...$$
> to:
> $$a_n = 3a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}$$
> ?

The usual trick is to use $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$ to cancel the sums.

For each $n\ge 4$ we have

$a_n=n+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i(n-i)$,

$a_{n-1}=n-1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} a_i(n-1-i)$.

So $a_n-a_{n-1}=1+a_{n-1}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} a_i$.

Similarly

$a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}=1+a_{n-2}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-3} a_i$.

So $(a_n-a_{n-1})-(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})=(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})-a_{n-2}$,

that is $a_n=3a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A generating function approach. We consider the recurrence relation
\begin{align*}
a_n&=3a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}\qquad\qquad n\geq 3\tag{1}\\
a_1&=1\\
a_2&=3
\end{align*}
and want to show this relation fulfills
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{a_n=n+a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}+3a_{n-3}+\cdots}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

Setting $n=2$ in the recurrence relation (1) we find from $a_2=3a_1-a_0$ that $a_0=0$. We consider the generating function
\begin{align*}
A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n=z+3z^2+21z^3+55z^4+\cdots
\end{align*}

> Using the Ansatzmethode we obtain from (1)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_nz^n}
> &=3\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-1}z^n-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-2}z^n\tag{3}\\
> &=3z\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-1}z^{n-1}-z^2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-2}z^{n-2}\\
> &=3z\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}-z^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}\\
> &=3z\left(A(z)-a_0\right)-z^2A(z)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(3z-z^2\right)A(z)}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

Since the left-hand side in (3) is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_nz^n=A(z)-a_0-a_1z=A(z)-z
\end{align*}
we get from (4)
\begin{align*}
A(z)-z&=\left(3z-z^2\right)A(z)\\
\color{blue}{A(z)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{z}{1-3z+z^2}}\tag{5}
\end{align*}

We now have to show that $a_n$ also fulfills the recurrence relation (2).

> We consider a sequence $b_n, n\geq 0$ fulfilling (2) with the same starting values $b_0=0, b_1=1, b_2=3$ and show it has the same generating function $A(z)$. We start with
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{b_n}&=n+b_{n-1}+2b_{n-2}+3b_{n-3}+\cdots\\
> &\color{blue}{=n+\sum_{k=0}^nkb_{n-k}}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
> and write this recurrence relation using generating functions. We get
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{B(z)}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nz^n\tag{7}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nz^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^nkb_{n-k}\right)z^n\\
> &=z\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nz^{n-1}+\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kz^k\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}b_lz^l\right)\tag{8}\\
> &=z\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)+\left(z\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)\right)B(z)\tag{9}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}+\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}B(z)}\tag{10}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (8) we use the *[Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)* of power series.
- In (9) we have the derivation of the *geometric series* $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}$.

> We get from (7) and (10)
> \begin{align*}
> B(z)&=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}+\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}B(z)\\
> B(z)(1-z)^2&=z+zB(z)\\
> B(z)\left(1-2z+z^2\right)&=z+zB(z)\\
> \color{blue}{B(z)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{z}{1-3z+z^2}}
> \end{align*}
> We conclude since the generating function $B(z)=A(z)$, that $a_n, n\geq 0$ also fulfills the recurrence relation (6) resp. (2) and the claim follows.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I needed to get from $a_n = n + a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2} + 3a_{n-3} ...$ to $a_n = 3a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}$, but as I said - your solution is very informative, provides much inside for anybody to understand similar problems. Thank you!

Comment: @thefool: You're welcome. You might observe that you are free to start as well from (6) to (10) and continue then with (1) to (5). It's just a matter of convenience.

Answer (score 1):

It does work. You just need to consider $a_0 = 1$ since there is, so to speak, $1$ way of choosing if there is no student at all.

Comment: Nonempty teams.

Comment: The teams have to be non-empty

Comment: Setting $a_0=1$ is a useful convention here.  It makes the recurrence formula simple, doesn't matter if it makes a lot of sense on its own.

Comment: @thefool sure, the all the teams are non-empty in that choice (since there are no teams).