# Probability of getting certain number of points

Tags: probability, combinatorics, generating-functions, dynamic-programming

> A one on one basketball tournament is happening in your community.  Each game has a point system.  3 points for a win, 1 point for a tie, and 0 points for a loss.  You have a 50% chance on winning, 40% chance of losing and a 10% of tying.  We will say all these events are independent.
>
> What's the probability by the end of 6 games you have at least 12 points.

This is my work for this question.
Let X be the number of points after 6 games, then

$ P(X \ge 12)=1-(3(\frac{1}{2})^6+1(\frac{1}{10})^6+0(\frac{4}{10})^6)=\frac{238281}{250000}$

I am not confident in it though.  Can somebody explain how I am approaching this right or wrong..

Comment: Can you explain your reason to obtain that probability?

Comment: I am not sure if correct but basically at least usually you subtract from one and since 6 games are played .5 of the time your going to win so *$\frac{1}{2}^6$ and this argument holds for the other probabilites.  I multiplied each probability by total points being earned

Comment: I think you are confused between expectation and probability.

Comment: Should I not be including the point values in my calculation then?

Answer (score 1):

The correct probability is $277/800$.  One way to calculate it is as follows.  First, list the possible $(W,T,L)$ triples with $W + T + L = 6$, $3W + 1T + 0L \ge 12$, and $W, T, L \ge 0$:
$$\{(3,3,0),(4,0,2),(4,1,1),(4,2,0),(5,0,1),(5,1,0),(6,0,0)\}$$

Now the desired probability is
$$\sum_{(W,T,L)} \binom{6}{W,T,L} 0.5^W 0.1^T 0.4^L = \frac{277}{800}.$$
Here, $$\binom{6}{W,T,L}=\frac{6!}{W!T!L!}$$ is a multinomial coefficient, which can also be written as $$\binom{6}{W}\binom{6-W}{T}\binom{6-W-T}{L}=\binom{6}{W}\binom{6-W}{T}\binom{L}{L}=\binom{6}{W}\binom{6-W}{T}.$$

---

An alternative approach uses recursion.  Let $w(p,g)$ denote the probability of at least $p$ points in the next $g$ games.  We want to compute $w(12,6)$.  By conditioning on the outcome of the next game, we obtain:
$$
w(p,n) = 
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $p\le 0$ and $g=0$}\\
0 &\text{if $p>0$ and $g=0$}\\
0.5 w(p-3,g-1) + 0.1 w(p-1,g-1) + 0.4 w(p,g-1) &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
The resulting values of $w$ are:
$$\begin{matrix}
p\backslash g &0 &1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 \\
\hline
0 &1.00000 &1.00000 &1.00000 &1.00000 &1.00000 &1.00000 &1.00000 \\
1 &0.00000 &0.60000 &0.84000 &0.93600 &0.97440 &0.98976 &0.99590 \\
2 &0.00000 &0.50000 &0.76000 &0.88800 &0.94880 &0.97696 &0.98976 \\
3 &0.00000 &0.50000 &0.75000 &0.87600 &0.93920 &0.97056 &0.98592 \\
4 &0.00000 &0.00000 &0.35000 &0.63500 &0.80960 &0.90496 &0.95392 \\
5 &0.00000 &0.00000 &0.25000 &0.51500 &0.71350 &0.84076 &0.91528 \\
6 &0.00000 &0.00000 &0.25000 &0.50000 &0.68950 &0.81675 &0.89606 \\
7 &0.00000 &0.00000 &0.00000 &0.20000 &0.44750 &0.65275 &0.79526 \\
8 &0.00000 &0.00000 &0.00000 &0.12500 &0.32750 &0.53250 &0.69866 \\
9 &0.00000 &0.00000 &0.00000 &0.12500 &0.31250 &0.50250 &0.66263 \\
10 &0.00000 &0.00000 &0.00000 &0.00000 &0.11250 &0.30000 &0.49663 \\
11 &0.00000 &0.00000 &0.00000 &0.00000 &0.06250 &0.20000 &0.37625 \\
12 &0.00000 &0.00000 &0.00000 &0.00000 &0.06250 &0.18750 &0.34625 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
In particular, $w(12,6)=277/800$.

Comment: I get what your saying until the "Now the desired..." are we plugging in the values above for W, T, L? Cause I tried that for the first one and got nothing close to what you got

Comment: I updated my answer just now with more detail.

Comment: I like your solutions, but I think you have the probabilities of losing and tying switched in your calculations.  It shoud be $P(loss) = 0.4$ and $P(tie) = 0.1$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it out.  I was fooled by the inconsistent ordering in the problem statement.  I corrected my answer just now, and it matches yours.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using a probability generating function.  Readers unfamiliar with generating functions may find many applicable resources in the answers to this question: [How can I learn about generating functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3142386/how-can-i-learn-about-generating-functions/3142387)

A probability generating function for the total number of points in six rolls is
$$f(x) = (0.4 + 0.1 x + 0.5 x^3)^6$$
On expansion of the polynomial,
$$f(x) = 0.004096\, +0.006144 x+0.00384 x^2+0.032 x^3+ \\0.03864 x^4+0.019224 x^5+0.100801
   x^6+0.0966 x^7+ \\0.03603 x^8+0.166 x^9+0.120375 x^{10}+0.03 x^{11}+ \\0.1525
   x^{12}+0.075 x^{13}+0.009375 x^{14}+0.075 x^{15}+ \\0.01875 x^{16}+0.015625
   x^{18}$$
(This is easy if you use a computer algebra system or Wolfram Alpha, otherwise a bit tedious.)
The coefficient of $x^n$ in this polynomial is the probability of winning $n$ points.  So if we want the probability of winning $12$ or more points, we can just sum up the coefficients of $x^{12}$ through $x^{18}$:

$$0.1525+0.075+0.009375+0.075 +0.01875+0.015625 = \boxed{0.34625}$$