# Are generating functions always elements of a ring of formal power series?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ring-theory, generating-functions, formal-power-series

I am trying to understand what generating functions are, so I looked at Wikipedia.

**Excerpt:**

> In mathematics, a **generating function** is a way of encoding an infinite sequence of numbers $(a_n)$ by treating them as the coefficients of a formal power series. This series is called the generating function of the sequence.
>
> ...
>
> The *ordinary generating function* of a sequence $a_n$ is
>
> $$G(a_n;x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n x^n.$$

**Discussion:**

I am trying to understand this definition relative to things I already have some familiarity with. I know a small amount about formal power series and formal power series rings.

I suppose that if we have a sequence $(a_n)$ and ring $R$ such that all $a_i \in R$, then a generating function $g$ is just an element of the formal power series ring $R[[X]]$. However, presumably there are generating functions that do not belong to a ring of formal power series, because the components of the sequence are not required to be elements of a ring.

On second thought, I'm not sure it makes sense to consider sequences $(a_n)$ whose components are not ring elements, because then as far as I know your formal power series is just a string $a_0 + a_1 X + a_2 X^2 + \dots$ without any additional structure, in which case the definition of a generating function does not lead to any gain, since you're still just dealing with a sequence.

So, would it be appropriate to think of a generating function as an element of a ring of formal power series?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, it's implicit that the elements of a sequence are elements of a ring.  Usually real numbers.  So yes, it's appropriate to think of a generating function an an element in the ring of formal power series.

Comment: @Novice To learn more about generating functions, you may want to try using some of the resources listed in [How can I learn about generating functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3142386/602049).