# Probability of *at least* k same specific digits in an n-digit sequence?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

Given an n-digit integer sequence, e.g. $n=5$ `[1, 1, 5, 6, 4]` where each digit is independent and uniformly random in the range 1-6, what is the probability of having *at least* k same digits of a certain value (e.g. 1)?

Specifically I'm interested in $k = n/2$ (rounded up) and n in the range 1 - 40.

So ... `f(k, n) = Probability of *at least* k same of a specific digit = ... n ... k ...?`

---

Background:

This is as far as I got with the question of plotting the probability of rolling $n$ dice once and having at least $k$ `1`s in the resulting roll. (e.g. at least half the dice showing `1`.)

Yes, there are $6^n$ combinations to roll $n$ dice. The probability for each die to show or not show a `1` is $1/6$ or $5/6$ respectively.

Yes, the question is the same whether asking if we have at least half `1`s or at least half `4`s ... any single digit, the others are irrelevant. And, yes, it does not matter if I roll $n$ dice once to generate the sequence or one die $n$ times.

That it is $1/6$ for one die is trivial. For two dice I can come up with a calculation, and is still easy to check with a table - $11/36$), but I fail to come up with a calculable general solution for $n >= 3$

Similar to [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4301206/what-is-the-probability-of-rolling-x-of-the-same-any-not-specific-dice-out-of) I'm currently looking at the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) but I'm stuck a bit at the moment.

Side Side Note: The question for increasing n comes from a discussion we had on if, and how much, the probability of rolling more than half `1`s with a hand full of D6 dice increases with the number of dice.

Comment: If $~f(r) = ~$ the probability of **exactly** $~r~$ digits equal to $~1,~$ then the desired computation is $~\sum_{r=k}^n f(r).~$  See [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), 
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(k, n) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$
Where $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways to choose $k$ successes from $n$, which accounts for all the combinations of dice that would roll successfully without duplicates.

$p^k$ is the probability of each success to the power of desired successes.

$(1-p)^{n-k}$ is the probability of failure to the power of number of failures.

In this case, you are assuming that you will have exactly $k$ successes and $(n-k)$ failures. If you want to find *at least* $k$ successes, you have to add all the possible outcomes from $k$ to $n$: $$P(k, n) = \sum_{k=x}^n\binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

We can also write it as a probability with the number of successful cases over the total number of cases. In this case, $p$ is the number of options (6 for dice):

$$P(k, n) = \frac{\binom{n}{k}(p-1)^{n-k}}{p^n}$$
Or for *at least* k successes:
$$P(k, n) = \sum_{k=x}^n\frac{\binom{n}{k}(p-1)^{n-k}}{p^n}$$

Comment: *If you want to find at least k successes, you can omit the failure term*. I think, this is wrong. You overcount a lot. Consider there was $k+1$ ones. You can choose $k$ ones from $k+1$ multiple ways and you count that as different combinations.

Comment: To find at least $k$ successes one must add all the relevant “exact” probabilities: $P(k,n)+P(k+1,n)+…+P(n,n)$.

Comment: You are correct, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Part answer to the last side note:

I've managed to plot this [via Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=DiscretePlotSum%5BDivide%5Bn%21%2Ck%21*%5C%2840%29n-k%5C%2841%29%21%5D*Power%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2C6%5D%5C%2841%29%2Ck%5D*Power%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B5%2C6%5D%5C%2841%29%2Cn-k%5D%2C%7Bk%2CCeiling%5C%2891%29Divide%5Bn%2C2%5D%5C%2893%29%2Cn%7D%5Dfor%20n%20%3D%2020%20to%2040) and the result is quite interesting in that - contrary to my intuition - the probability of having `>= n/2` identical sides of any die face (e.g. half or more than half 1s) decreases rapidly:

[image: n=2 to 40]