# What is the probability that the sum of 6 four-sided dice is less than or equal to 14?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, dice

The solution given is shown below.

My question is how did they count the numerator like that?
What is the explanation for it please?

$$\begin{align}
\frac{C_6^{14}-C_1^6\times C_6^{10}+C_2^6 \times C_6^6}{4^6}&=\frac{3003-6\times 210+15\times 1}{4^6}\\
&= \frac{1758}{4^6}\\
&= \frac{879}{2048}
\end{align}$$

I understand  the denominator namely because each of the four sided dice has four choices and six of them so, all possible outcomes will be $4^6$.

I believe that the 4-sided dice here has 1, 2, 3, 4 printed on its faces.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Sum of 6 four-sided-dice can be less or equal than 14 (proba=$P_0$), or equal to 15 (proba=$P_1$) or greater or egal than 16 (proba = $P_0$, same as first term, by symmetry). So we can compute $P_1$ proba to obtain exactly 15, and then $P_0=\frac{1-P_1}{2}$

Comment: They are applying PIE in that numerator (as opposed to the complicated GF solutions shown below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following solution uses a generating function.  Readers not familiar with generating functions can find several resources in the answers to this question: [How can I learn about generating functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3142386/how-can-i-learn-about-generating-functions/3142387)

There are $4^6$ possible outcomes when rolling six four-sided dice, all of which we assume are equally likely. We want to count the number of arrangements in which the sum is less than or equal to $14$.  This is the number of solutions in integers to
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6 \le 14$$
sunbject to $1 \le x_i \le 4$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5,6$.  Equivalently, we want the number of integer solutions to
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7 = 14 \tag{1}$$
where $0 \le x_7$. The generating function for the number of solutions is
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= (x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^6 \cdot (1+x+x^2+ \dots) \\
&= x^6 \left( \frac{1-x^4}{1-x} \right)^6 \cdot \frac{1}{1-x} \tag{2} \\
&= x^6 \; (1-x^4)^6 \; (1-x)^{-7} \\
&= x^6 \; (1 -6x^4+15x^8+O(x^{12})) \; \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \binom{7+i-1}{i} \tag{3} x^i
\end{align}$$
From $(3)$ we can see that the coefficient of $x^{14}$ in $f(x)$ is
$$[x^{14}]f(x) = \binom{7+8-1}{8} - 6 \binom{7+4-1}{4} + 15 = 1758$$
so the number of solutions to $(1)$ is $1758$, and the probability of rolling a sum of $14$ or less is
$$\frac{1758}{4^6}$$
**Notes:**

$(2)$  Summing geometric series (twice).

$(3)$  Applying the Binomial Theorem, first for a positive exponent and then for a negative exponent.

Comment: This is the best written solution and most practical for competition too, thanks a lot!

Comment: @archismanpanigrahi Thank you for an extremely helpful edit. I am afraid attention to details is not my strong point.

Answer (score 4):

### Simplified Answer

**There are two forms of stars and bars, for positive integers with formula $\large\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ and for non-negative integers with formula** $\large\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$

I shall use the latter (to tally with the book solution), and add a *slack* variable $s$ to convert the desired sum from *upto* to *exactly*

With these changes, we need to solve over the non-negative integers for

$x_1 +x_2 +x_3 +x_4 +x_5 +x_6 +s = 14-6 = 8,\;\{ x_i \leq3\}$

Then using stars and bars with inclusion-exclusion, (note that there is no upper limit on the slack variable)

Number of ways $$=\binom{14}6 - \binom61\binom{10}6 + \binom62\binom66 = 1758$$

Answer (score 2):

Integer Composition of a numebr $\leq 14$,

summand in $[1,4]$

$6$ summands

---

the number of IntegerCompositions of $n$ to $k$ summands with summand in $[1,r]$

$$
\left[z^n\right]\left(z+z^2+\ldots z^r\right)^k=\left[z^n\right]\left(z \frac{1-z^r}{1-z}\right)^k=\sum_j(-1)^j\left(\begin{array}{c}
k \\
j
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-r j-1 \\
k-1
\end{array}\right)
$$

for your case,
$r=4,k=6$

$6 \leq n\leq 14$

## Series Coefficient

```
SeriesCoefficient[(z*(1 - z^r)/(1 - z))^k /. {k -> 6, r -> 4}, {z, 
    0, #}] & /@ Range[6, 14, 1]

Total@% /(4^6)
```

$$
{1, 6, 21, 56, 120, 216, 336, 456, 546}
\\
\frac{879}{2048}
$$

## Binomial sum

```
a[n_, r_, k_] := 
 Sum[(-1)^j*Binomial[k, j]*Binomial[n - r*j - 1, k - 1], {j, 0, 
   Min[Floor[(n - k)/r], k]}]
a[#, 4, 6] & /@ Range[6, 14, 1]
```

$$
{1, 6, 21, 56, 120, 216, 336, 456, 546}
\\
\frac{879}{2048}
$$

Comment: Which software is it?

Comment: I wrote Mathematica code to make some calculation.

Comment: Thank you. This has been helpful!

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming you're familiar with Stars-and-Bars. If not, see true blue anil's solution which deals with that part of it.)

Consider finding the sum of 6 positive integers that is at most $14$, which is equivalent to 7 non-negative integers that sum to exactly $14-6=8$ (where the last variable is the dummy variable for the remainder). By Stars-and-bars, there are ${14 \choose 6 }$ ways of doing so.

Let $A_i$ be the event that the $i$th integer is 5 or more.
We're interested in $ | \cup A_i |$, which is the complement to "each is at most 4".
Notice that since $ 4 + 4 + 4 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 15 > 14$, hence at most 2 dice can show 5 or more. So $|A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k| = 0 $.
Thus, by PIE, $ | \cup A_i | = \sum |A_i| - \sum |A_i \cap A_j|$ (since the larger terms are all 0).

By Stars-and-Bars again, $|A_i| = {14 - 4 \choose 6 } $ and $ |A_i \cap A_j | = { 14 - 4 - 4 \choose 6}$.
There are clearly $ 6 \choose 1 $ events $ A_i$ and $ {6 \choose 2 }$ events $ A_i \cap A_j$.
So $ | \cup A_i |= \sum |A_i| - \sum |A_i \cap A_j| = { 6 \choose 1 } { 10 \choose 6} - { 6 \choose 2 } { 6 \choose 6}$

Hence, the number of ways is $ {14 \choose 6} - { 6 \choose 1 } { 10 \choose 6} + { 6 \choose 2 } { 6 \choose 6}.$

Comment: Thank you for explaining what they did!