Generating function and enumerative combinatorial problems
I’m a high school student, and I’m currently working on an essay about to what extent could generating function help solve combinatorial problems. This is a general question and topic, I don’t know whether it’s a topic that I could do some research. Also, I don’t know where to start. Should I change my research question? If I need to finish this research what should I do first? Please help me.

Maybe Chapter 1 of Wilf's book would be a good place to start?

Is this IB EE or IA? If so, you should probably be a little more specific about the kind of combinatorial problems.

@NaitikMundra Yes, this is EE. I also think this is less specific, but i don't know how to classify combinatorial problems and how to choose problems for my research question.

In my experience, a good IB Math EE involves doing math by developing a mathematical result on your own instead of just researching and writing about a math topic.

@LucemL If you do not know, it is a good indication that you should research way more, before even considering a research question. Alternatively, choose an easier topic

@Karl, While good advice, just writing about a maths topic is fine as well, as long as you do some of your own analysis, give examples.

@NaitikMundra How could I start? Reading books?

The text by Wilf that @angryavian suggested is probably the best place to start

@NaitikMundra Thank you!

The answers to this question should give you plenty of sources: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3142386/how-can-i-learn-about-generating-functions/3142387
